# How to compute a more general version of Vandermonde / Cauchy double alternant determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinants

Consider some variables $\{X_i\}_{1\le i \le n}$, $\{Y_i\}_{1\le i \le n}$, and $\{W_i\}_{1\le i \le n}$. Does anyone know how to compute the following determinant?
$$
\det ~ \left(\frac{W_j^{i-1}}{X_i+Y_j}\right)_{1\le i,j\le n}.
$$

Update: If you could also provide an answer for the case where $W_j=1$ for $j\ge2$, that would be sufficient for the problem I have encountered in my research.

Comment: It's easy to come up with families of matrices; you had another one at https://mathoverflow.net/questions/358175/how-to-prove-the-determinant-of-a-hilbert-like-matrix-with-parameter-is-non-zero .  Before asking multiple questions of this sort, I think that it is appropriate to give some more information about how this arises, and why it is of particular significance (as opposed to just one of a sequence of close but not identical questions).

Comment: Thanks for your comment @LSpice. As I mentioned in my question, these matrices are coming up in some polynomial regression that I'm doing for my research. I have been going over Christian Krattenthaler's "Advanced Determinant Calculus", and I realized I can state my question in a more general format as you can see in the new edition of my question.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can get something out of the technique of displacement equations. It works as follows.

Notice, first, that a matrix $A$ is a Cauchy-like matrix if and only if it satisfies the so-called displacement equation $LA-AR = vu^T$, where $L$ and $R$ are diagonal matrices (containing the nodes) and $vu^T$ is a generic rank-1 term.

Suppose you are given a matrix $A$.

1. Find (if you can!) two matrices $L$ and $R$ such that $LA-AR = vu^T$ has rank 1. If $A$ is a Cauchy matrix $A_{ij} = \frac{1}{X_i + Y_j}$, then $L = diag(X_i)$ and $R = diag(Y_j)$ work, while for a Vandermonde matrix $A = W_j^{i-1}$ then $L$ is a shift matrix and $R$ is $diag(W_j)$.
2. Diagonalize (if you can do it explicitly) $L = VD_LV^{-1}$ and $R=UD_RU^{-1}$, and then with some algebra you get $D_L V^{-1}AU - V^{-1}AUD_R = V^{-1}vu^TU$.
3. Then, $V^{-1}AU$ is a Cauchy matrix with nodes the entries of $D_L$ and $D_R$, because of that displacement equation. You can compute its determinant, and use it to get the determinant of $A$.

Answer (score 0):

My conjecture is that the answer is close to this:
$$
\frac{\prod_{1\le i < j \le n} (X_j - X_i) (W_jY_j - W_iY_i)}
{\prod_{1\le i ,j \le n}(X_i + Y_j)}.
$$

Comment: For $n = 2$, the determinant is a fraction whose numerator is an irreducible degree-$3$ polynomial. So I don't think the answer is that easy.

Comment: @darijgrinberg For $n=2$, my conjectured answer has a numerator which is an irreducible degree-3 polynomial too. Am I missing something?

Comment: Yours is not irreducible.

Comment: @darijgrinberg I see, Thanks!